# Texture.update() throwing exceptions

Tags: c++, sfml

It says

> ```
>  Assertion failed: x + window.getSize().x <= m_size.x
> ```

Size and x\y are correct.
It all breaks on last line. I need it for selection and copy/paste tool.

```
    bufferRect.width = abs(curPos.x - point1.x);
    bufferRect.height = abs(curPos.y - point1.y);
    int width = bufferRect.width;
    int height = bufferRect.height;
    int x = bufferRect.left;
    int y = bufferRect.top;
    cout << "width is "<< bufferRect.width << endl;
    cout << "height is " << bufferRect.height << endl;
    cout << "left and top are " << bufferRect.left << " + " << bufferRect.top << endl;

    bufferTexture.create(width, height);
    bufferTexture.update(mainWindow, x, y);
```

Comment: So if you're debugging line by line are you sure that `x + window.getSize().x <= m_size.x` meets the condition when you're calling the function that complains? Also note that `assert();` is a bit different from `throw exception;`. It tests mostly preconditions that should be fulfilled with a function call. These are usually only applying in `DEBUG` mode builds.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, it meets the condition. I made the test where I put mainWindow.getSize().x and mainWindow.getSize().y in the parameters .create(), and it works. However, when I put a certain number or variable, it breaks.